# How can I get list from node-schedule?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
```

I think get from schedule or insert to db and get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

```
var list = schedule.scheduledJobs;
```

For this to work you have to schedule a job first, like so:

```
var mainObj = {
    dayOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    minute: 50,
    hour: 12
}

var message = schedule.scheduleJob("Announcement1", mainObj, function() {
    console.log('hi');
})
```

Comment: Well, if you do the same function with a different object you would create another job. Therefore you can keep scheduling as many jobs as you like.

Comment: Can we schedule a job in one file and access it from another file?

Comment: @jazeb007 in order to do this, you would need to export the job variable from your module, then in the other file import this variable; take a look at this website: https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: This is what i was thinking about this solution but i thought if there is any function in scheduler that can show current schedules but i think module export is the current solution for now.
Thanks for suggestion @gegs921